# sklearn (Bad Input Shape) ValueError

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, naivebayes

I am new to the world of ML and sklearn. I tried to use GaussianNB on a dataset with `X_train[2500,800]`, `Y_train[2500,8]`.

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
clf = GaussianNB()
clf.fit(X, Y)
```

On running the program, it is showing

> ValueError: bad input shape (2500, 8).

How do i convert `Y_train[2500,8]` to `Y_train[2500,1]`?

Comment: What is your data ? do you have `2500` samples with `800` features ?

Comment: Yes. 2500 samples. And y has 8 labels. But classifier accepts only one column

Comment: `Y_train` should be a list of target values, that is, a list in which the ith element is the class label of the ith training case in your data set. It, therefore, has to be one-dimensional. Hence, if your `Y_train` is of shape (2500, 8), you mixed something up maybe.

Comment: Is this a multi-label classification? i.e can a single sample have multiple labels in y (from those 8 labels) or each will have only single label?

Comment: @robertpatrik I think there's a mistake in the question, are you sure you have ` X_train[2500,800]` did you mean `X_train[2500,8]` instead? Also, out of the 8 labels, do you know which is your target variable?

Comment: well, if you labels are in the `ont_hot` format, just do `Y_train = np.argmax(Y_train, axis=1)`

Comment: Thanks @IshantMrinal. Its Working.

Comment: @VivekKumar how to solve this error if it is a multi-label classification? ie. each training item can have multiple labels which means y is not one dimensional.

Comment: @fateh Which classifier are you using? GaussianNB? If so, then it does not support 2-d `y` inherently. Either you need to use [OneVsRestClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html) to reduce the multi-label problem to multiple binary problems or use a different algorithm which supports multi-label cases. See [this for more details](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html). It would be better if you provide more details (preferably in a new question).

Comment: @VivekKumar I am using logistic regression classifier and dimension of y is (237,15).

Comment: @fateh `LogisticRegression` in sklearn doesn't support multi-label directly, as its not present under "`Support multilabel`" heading in the page I linked. So you would have to use OneVsRestClassifier only for that.

Comment: you mean "onevsrest" or "make_multilabel_classification" ?
in my case training items can have multiple labels so I believe I have to use "make_multilabel_classification". Is that right?

Comment: @fateh `make_multilabel_classification` produces a new dummy dataset for examples. If you already have the data, you will not use the `make_multilabel_classification`.

Answer (score 2):

OP is using a one hot encoder so the fit function won't work with the array @Ishant Mrinal recommends this

```
Y_train = np.argmax(Y_train, axis=1)
```

That will allow you to pass the one hot encoding into the fit function.