# Scikitlearn LinearSVC Bad input shape

Tags: scikit-learn, svm

I'm trying to use LinearSVC on my data! My code below:

```
from sklearn import svm

clf2 = svm.LinearSVC()
clf2.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Results in the following error:

```
ValueError: bad input shape (2190, 9)
```

I've used one-hot encoding on my y value before splitting into y_test and y_train, and believe this to be the issue. I've tried implementing similar fixes ([sklearn (Bad Input Shape) ValueError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45768899/sklearn-bad-input-shape-valueerror)) but still get errors when I try and re-shape.

After one hot-encoding, I have a target variable (y) that has 9 classes, and there are a total of 2190 samples i'm running. It seems I need to reduce these 9 classes to 1 class in order to fit the SVM.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: We don't have your data and can't run this or deduce all shapes from this snippet. But if this bad input shape is linked to y_train, read the docs to see this is not valid input!

Comment: thanks for response! I edited my post to attempt to make it more clear

Comment: Compare a target vector of shape ```(2,3)``` like ```[[0,0,1], [1,0,0]]``` with a shape ```(2,)``` one like ```[2,0]```. This, together with reading the docs should solve your problem!

Comment: @Ben try to reshape the X_train and y_train so that they look like X_train = [100,10] and y_train = [100,]. before you use clf2.fit can you print the shapes of these two arrays and post the results ?

Comment: @Ben also, can you add the data? or an example?

Comment: Please consider adding the code snippet with some minimal data, for better understanding and for the reproduction of the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LinearSVC dont accept 2-d values for `y`. As [documented](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.fit):

Parameters:

```
y : array-like, shape = [n_samples]

    Target vector relative to X
```

So you don't need to convert into one-hot encoded matrix. Just supply them as is, even if its strings. They will be internally handled correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Accoding to the [document](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html),
you may try *sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier* as follows:

```py
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC

clf = OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC())
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 1):

**You need to reshape the arrays**. Here is an example using random data and as target variable a variable that contains 5 classes:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm

# 100 samples and 10 features
x = np.random.rand(100, 10) 

#5 classes
y = [1,2,3,4,5] * 20

x = np.asarray(x)
y = np.asarray(y)

print(x.shape)
print(y.shape)

clf2 = svm.LinearSVC()
clf2.fit(x, y)
```

Results:

```
(100, 10)

(100,)

LinearSVC(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=True, fit_intercept=True,
     intercept_scaling=1, loss='squared_hinge', max_iter=1000,
     multi_class='ovr', penalty='l2', random_state=None, tol=0.0001,
     verbose=0)
```