# ValueError: bad input shape (2, 256, 3) when trying to compute ROC curve

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, roc

First, I'm new to python. Trying to build a ROC curve, I am getting an error on this code line:

```
fpr_keras, tpr_keras, thresholds_keras = roc_curve(Y_test.argmax(axis=1), decoded_imgs.argmax(axis=1))
```

error:

> ValueError: bad input shape (2, 256, 3)

When I try to shape after reshape I get a second error:

> TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45768899/sklearn-bad-input-shape-valueerror), but I don't understand what should i do, I'm stacking on this problem. Can somebody edit my code? This is what I'm trying to do: [link2](https://www.dlology.com/blog/simple-guide-on-how-to-generate-roc-plot-for-keras-classifier/)

```
import keras
import numpy as np
from keras.datasets import mnist
from get_dataset import get_dataset
from stack import keras_model

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = get_dataset()

from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D, Dense
from keras.models import Model

input_img = Input(shape=(256, 256, 3))

x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(3, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)
autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mae',metrics=['mse', 'accuracy'])

from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, TensorBoard
checkpoints = []

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

generated_data = ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_center=False, samplewise_center=False, featurewise_std_normalization=False, samplewise_std_normalization=False, zca_whitening=False, rotation_range=0,  width_shift_range=0.1, height_shift_range=0.1, horizontal_flip = True, vertical_flip = False)
generated_data.fit(X_train)
epochs = 1
batch_size = 5

autoencoder.fit_generator(generated_data.flow(X_train, X_train, batch_size=batch_size), steps_per_epoch=X_train.shape[0]/batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_data=(X_test, X_test), callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir='/tmp/autoencoder')])

autoencoder.fit(X_train, X_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_data=(X_test, X_test), shuffle=True, callbacks=[TensorBoard(log_dir='/tmp/auti')])

decoded_imgs = autoencoder.predict(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
#2 256  3
print(decoded_imgs.argmax(axis=1))
print(decoded_imgs.argmax(axis=1).reshape(1,3))

fpr_keras, tpr_keras, thresholds_keras = roc_curve(Y_test.argmax(axis=1), decoded_imgs.argmax(axis=1))

ValueError: bad input shape (2, 256, 3)
```

after editing the line to :

```
fpr_keras, tpr_keras, thresholds_keras = roc_curve(Y_test.argmax(axis=1), decoded_imgs.reshape(6,256,1))
```

i get this error :

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 4]

Comment: Welcome to SO; 1) please **remove all commented-out code**, as well all print/plot commands for which you don't provide output (see why [a wall of code isn't helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/)) 2) remove also all code that comes **after** the error-producing line, since it is never executed and thus is irrelevant to the issue 3) fix your first line of code, which is arguably at the heart of the issue 4) post a sample of your `Y_test` & `decoded_imgs` (again, these are at the heart of your issue)

Comment: @desertnaut i edited my code can you now fix it please ?

Comment: There is still code after `fpr_keras, tpr_keras, thresholds_keras = roc_curve(Y_test.argmax(axis=1), decoded_imgs.argmax(axis=1).reshape(6,256,1))` (what does this random forest doing there??), which BTW is different from the command you show in the beginning of your post... Please put the **exact** command producing the error in-place, and delete everything after it

Comment: "when i try to shape after reshape i get a second error" this is presumably because you're using `a.shape()` when you inspect the shape after reshaping, you simply need to drop the parentheses: `a.shape`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You sound a little confused regarding the very basics of both ROC curves and autoencoders...

Quoting from the scikit-learn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_curve.html) of `roc_curve`:

> **roc_curve** *(y_true, y_score, pos_label=None, sample_weight=None, drop_intermediate=True)*
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> **y_true : *array, shape = [n_samples]***
>
> True binary labels. If labels are not either {-1, 1} or {0, 1}, then pos_label should be explicitly given.
>
> **y_score : *array, shape =
>   [n_samples]***
>
> Target scores, can either be probability estimates of the positive class, confidence values, or non-thresholded measure of decisions (as
>   returned by “decision_function” on some classifiers).

In other words, both inputs to `roc_curve` should be simple one-dimensional arrays of scalar numbers, the first one containing the true classes and the second one the predicted scores.

Now, despite the fact that you don't show a sample of your own data, and while I don't doubt that your `Y_test.argmax(axis=1)` may conform to this specification, most certainly your `decoded_imgs.argmax(axis=1)` (however you reshape it) **does not**. Why? Because of the very nature of an autoencoder.

In sharp contrast to models like the Random Forest classifier you also attempt to use in a (now removed) part of your code, **autoencoders are not classifiers**: their function is to reconstruct a (denoised, compressed etc) version of their input, and *not* to produce class predictions (see the nice little [tutorial](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html) in the Keras blog for a quick orientation). Which, in your case, means that your `decoded_imgs` are actually transformed images (or image-like data, in any case), and not the class scores required by `roc_curve`, hence the error (which, technically speaking, is actually due to `decoded_imgs` not being a one-dimensional array, but hopefully you get the idea).

Even if you had used a classifier instead of an autoencoder here, you would have bumped upon another issue: ROC curves are used for *binary* classification tasks, and not for multi-class ones, like MNIST (there are actually some approaches applying them to multi-class data too, but they are not widely used AFAIK). It's true that, superficially, scikit-learn's `roc_curve` will work even in a multi-class setting:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import metrics

y = np.array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2]) # 3-class problem
scores = np.array([0.05, 0.1, 0.4, 0.35, 0.8])
fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y, scores, pos_label=2)  # works OK, no error
```

but actually this happens only because we have explicitly defined that `pos_label=2`, hence, under the hood, scikit-learn considers all labels other than `2` as the negative ones, and subsequently treats the rest of the computations as if our problem was a binary one (i.e. class `2` vs all other classes).

In your case (MNIST), you should ask yourself the question: *what exactly is a "positive" in the 10-class MNIST dataset?* And *does this question even make sense?* Hopefully, you should be able to convince yourself that the answer is not straightforward, as in the binary (0/1) case.

---

To wrap-up: there is no *coding* error here to be remedied; the root cause of your issue is simply that you attempt something meaningless and invalid, since autoencoders do not produce class predictions, hence their output cannot be used for computing a ROC curve. I kindly suggest to first get a solid understanding of the relevant notions and concepts, before proceeding to applications...

Comment: thanks for your answer @desertnaut, my goal is face recognition and the auto encoder in my code is used for denoising and data compression. I calculate the Euclidean distance and cosine similarity in another code. Only, to draw the ROC curve, I do not know what I have to transmit as inputs (scores?) To the ROC curve code to test the performance of my recognition system.

Comment: @GuizmoCharo It should be hopefully obvious by now that the ROC curve cannot be used to measure the performance of any data "denoising" or "compression", and that it is only a performance measure for *(binary) classification*. And since the answer arguably resolved your issue, kindly accept it (answers take up valuable time for respondents) - thanks.